# What is the difference between http and https in an intranet?

Tags: security

Is http ok vs https in an intranet connected to the internet ?
If a bank has a website which using http and only accessible if connected  to the network, is this a security risk?

Comment: Yes, everything should be HTTPS, even within an intranet.  Traffic should be encrypted in transit to ensure access to it is restricted at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but let me try an answer.

HTTPS has the objective to guarantee that no one in the middle of the connection is being able to see what you and the server are talking to each other, he does it using encryption, so even in an intranet using HTTPS has its advantages.

Imagine a wireless connection, everyone in the bank is in the middle of you and the connection with the router (consequently, the server) if you are using it, so if this website has sensitive information like a password, even in an intranet, you would want it secure so no one inside that network can sniff packets and get your password easily in a clear HTTP request.